Type-level tuple: how to avoid nesting in a type argument
Considering first-class-families library, I have a code:
import Fcf.Data.Common
import Fcf.Core

type T a b c = '(a, '(b, c))                                                                                                  
data D a b t = D                                                                                                              
  { a :: a                                                                                                                    
  , b :: b                                                                                                                    
  , c :: Eval (Fst t)                                                                                                         
  , d :: Eval (Fst (Eval (Snd t)))                                                                                            
  , e :: Eval (Snd (Eval (Snd t)))                                                                                            
  }                                                                                                                           
type MyT = T Int Int Bool                                                                                                     
data C = C (D Int Int MyT)

with nesting only because no Third (similarly to Fst and Snd). Is it possible to avoid this nesting in some more intelligent way? Maybe there is some operator allowing more flat "structure"? If no, what can be used instead of it?
Or from another point of view, maybe this code is not good:
Eval (Fst (Eval (Snd t)))

and there is a way to avoid the second Eval ?
Finally, I want D taking type-level tuple of size > 2 and to pass it in a "flat" form if it's possible.

The question is precise and answerable, and that is good, and somebody should write an answer to this exact question as asked. But I am concerned. Are you sure this is needed? The setup is a little odd, and it may be that some of your early design decisions, if reconsidered, would lead to a simpler/more orthodox arrangement and the question would evaporate in a puff of smoke. Once you get something working, consider taking your result to the code review stackexchange.

"Is it possible to avoid this nesting in some more intelligent way?" Presumably it's nested in that way to follow the structure of term-level [  ,  , ...] which is just sugar for ( : ( : ( : ...))). There are type-level tuples of arbitrary arity. But then you need arity-specific accessors: FstofThree, SndofThree, ThdofThree, ThdofFour, ...; or make Thd a type family with overloading for each possible arity.

@AntC yes, you are right. The problem is that I am not good in type-level programming :) Currently I did it exactly in this way (FstOfThree-style), but I think there are other options (a lot of libraries: type-level maps, sets, etc), I should learn some of them. Another problem that I hit, when I use such type-level evaluated types, I hit that deriving does not work more, and I need at least standalone deriving (or manually implementing instances).

In case this is an X-Y problem, please note that you don't need the first-class-families package to implement simple type-level functions.  You can just use type families directly.  So, the  following will work fine:
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family Fst triple where
  Fst (a,b,c) = a
type family Snd triple where
  Snd (a,b,c) = b
type family Thd triple where
  Thd (a,b,c) = c

type T a b c = (a, b, c)
data D a b t = D
  { a :: a
  , b :: b
  , c :: Fst t
  , d :: Snd t
  , e :: Thd t
  }
type MyT = T Int Int Bool
data C = C (D Int Int MyT)

Alternatively, you can define:
type T a b c = '(a, b, c)

and modify the type family definitions with ticks:
type family Fst triple where
  Fst '(a,b,c) = a
-- etc. --

which will work too.
Two observations:
First, there's actually a big conceptual difference between the first "no ticks" version and the second "ticks" version. It's the type-level equivalent of working in a dynamically typed language ("no ticks") and a statically typed language ("ticks"), but if you don't have a compelling reason to use the "ticks" version, you should stick with the "no ticks" version, as it's more straightforward and perfectly idiomatic and -- like dynamically typed programming in general -- comes with some usability advantages, like allowing you to define:
type family Fst tuple where
  Fst (a,b) = a
  Fst (a,b,c) = a
  Fst (a,b,c,d) = a
  -- and so on --

and use the same Fst function on different length tuples.
Second, the purpose of first-class-families is to permit partially applied type-level functions. If you needed to pass Fst to a Map function, for example:
type Result = Map Fst '[(Double,Char,String),(Int,Double,Double)]

then the type family definitions in this answer wouldn't work because type families can only appear in type expressions fully applied to all their arguments.
If you don't need to use partially (or unapplied) type-level functions, then you don't need first-class-families.
